# Android device is not responding

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I used Unity 2019. 
When I connect my android devices (3 devices, tablet included) to Unity and try to run and build any apk, devices are recongized in Unity but the compilation process fails. lt's, writtren :Android device 52000... is not responding

[image: Android device 52000... is not responding]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

the problem is very clear. The compilation is successful, which means there is nothing wrong with your code. And the error message in the dialog box is clearly saying that

> Make sure USB debugging has been enabled

So, to solve this simply follow the steps below -

1. Navigate to Settings > About Phone > Scroll to bottom > Tap Build number several times
2. Go back and now access the Developer options menu, check 'USB debugging' and click 'OK' on the prompt

You can also checkout this [link](https://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-USB-debugging-on-Android_id53909)

Comment: Thank you. I already followed all theses steps. USB debugging is also checked. I installed the drivers of my mobile phones

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem. 
In USB connection mode, on my phone, there are 4 options:

- Transfer files
- transfer images
- Connect a MIDI device
- Charge this phone.

I ONLY changed the connection mode to TRANSFER IMAGES. 
After that, I received a prompt asking me the validate this connection mode. I did it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my new phone, which was occurring even after enabling USB debugging and authorizing the PC through the phone. I ended up finding the answer in [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TroubleShootingAndroid.html) Unity's documentation:

> Run the `adb devices` command from the `platform-tools` directory of your
>   Android SDK installation and check the output.
>
> If the output list is empty and you are using Windows, you may need to
>   install the driver for ADB  devices. For more details, refer to the
>   Android SDK/NDK Setup documentation.
>
> If the list contains entries with the unauthorized label, you may need
>   to authorize your computer on your device and give it permission to
>   debug it. Check the device’s screen for the corresponding dialog.
>
> If the list contains your device with the device label, build your
>   Project in Unity again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue, by changing the USB connection mode to Image Transfer(PTP) in my MI device

Answer (score 0):

On android device, when prompted for "Allow USB debugging?", selecting "Always allow from this computer" checkbox solved the problem for me.

In order for my phone to show up the "Allow USB debugging?" dialog, I revoked the USB debugging authorisations from my android device and then ran "adb devices".

Also once I did this, unity was showing my device name instead of just device id.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

Windows key type `cmd`

`cd C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`